# Wordpress : Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4791

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing an issue when I try to filter custom post type archive by category.

I want to filter the shop of woocommerce by multiple categories, so I made a widget that display a form with all categories with a checkbox for each one.

The HTMl for this form is :

```
<form method="get">
  <?php foreach($cats as $cat) : ?>
     <p>
        <input 
          style="margin-bottom: 0;" 
          type="checkbox" 
          id="<?php echo $cat->slug?>" 
          name="product_cat[]" 
          value="<?php echo $cat->slug?>">

          <label style="margin: 5px 0 0 0; color: #777;" 
                 for="<?php echo $cat->slug?>" >
            <?php echo $cat->name; ?> (<?php echo $cat->count ?>)
          </label>
       </p>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <button class="button primary" style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit">
     <?php _e('Filtrer', 'themedomain');?>
   </button>
</form>
```

When I check one or more checkbox and submit the form i get this url

```
http://example.com/shop/?product_cat%5B%5D=chauffageclimatisation&product_cat%5B%5D=essencegaz
```

It seems great to me but i get this error message and no post is displaying :

```
Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /path/to/website/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4791
```

I'm pretty sure that this must be working because i've done it at my previous job but I can't access code to check that. Can someone help me with it ?

I also know that WordPress automatically filter post if you add terms separate with `','` in the query, like :

```
http://example.com/shop/?product_catchauffageclimatisation,essencegaz
```

But I don't know how to get this result with checkbox.

Comment: what's the PHP handling that form submit look like?

Comment: It should be automatically understand by WordPress so i should have nothing to do....  like in this URL of a website that i found: `https://popsciences.universite-lyon.fr/agenda/?ajax=1&recherche=&type-evenement%5B%5D=animation&type-evenement%5B%5D=ateliers&type-evenement%5B%5D=balade-urbaine&lieu=0&limit_down=&limit_up=` and at least it should not break the results because it's juste query parameters, so if i'm not doing anything with it in php the page should display correctly.

Comment: please give us the hole code

Answer (score 0):

```
function rclr_query_string($q)
{
    foreach (get_taxonomies(array(), 'objects') as $taxonomy => $t) {
        if ('post_tag' == $taxonomy) {
            continue;   // Handled further down in the $q['tag'] block
        }
        if ($t->query_var && !empty($q[$t->query_var])) {
            if (is_array($q[$t->query_var])) {
                $q[$t->query_var] = implode(',', $q[$t->query_var]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $q;
}

add_filter('request', 'rclr_query_string', 1);
```